# Automatically formatting a table from a file with a list of words

Tags: tables, datatool, csv

I have a list of ~1000 words in a text file. The words are listed in a text file `"my_words.txt"` with no breaklines as follows:

```
word1, word2, word3, etc.
```

I would like to display these words in a figure/table with vertical alignment (and central alignment within each column), i.e.

```
word1 word2 word3 word4
word5 word6 word7 word7
word8
```

where either I specify the number of rows or columns, or LaTeX figures them out from the width that I specify for the table.

I thought the package datatool could help with this problem, but I can't get it to work. I tried:

```
\usepackage{datatool}
% ...

\begin{document}
% ...

\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={source,package,target,brokenpkg,impactset,brokensource}]{mytable}{full_concept_list.csv}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \DTLdisplaydb{mytable}
 \caption{CSV Table test}
\end{table}
```

but I get the error:

```
Missing $ inserted 
\DTLdisplaydb{mytable}
```

Why is datatool not working? Are there other tools more appropiate for this task?

Comment: I don't think that a unique record for 1000 words is the best format. I'd use one word per line.

Comment: The underscores in `full_concept_list.csv` may be causing problems. LaTeX sometimes doesn't cope well with underscores in labels. Trying adding the `underscore` package. Alternatively, check your word list for any non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way with `expl3` and Heiko Oberdiek's `catchfile`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for the underscore
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \egreg_catchfiledef:nnn \CatchFileDef
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_catchfiledef:nnn { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnv }

\NewDocumentCommand{\storefile}{ m m } % #1 = symbolic name, #2 = file name
 {
  \egreg_catchfiledef:cnn { l_egreg_ #1 _list_tl } { #2 } { \char_set_catcode_other:N \_ }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printtable}{ m m } % #1 = number of columns, #2 = symbolic name
 {
  \egreg_printtable:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_egreg_temp_table_tl
\seq_new:N \l_egreg_temp_list_seq
\int_new:N \l_egreg_col_count_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_printtable:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnv \l_egreg_temp_list_seq { , } { l_egreg_ #2 _list_tl }
  \tl_clear:N \l_egreg_temp_table_tl
  \int_zero:N \l_egreg_col_count_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_egreg_temp_list_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_egreg_col_count_int
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_temp_table_tl { ##1 }
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_egreg_col_count_int = #1 }
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_temp_table_tl { \\ } \int_zero:N \l_egreg_col_count_int }
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_temp_table_tl { & } }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
  \l_egreg_temp_table_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\storefile{words}{my_words.txt}

\noindent Three words per line

\noindent\printtable{3}{words}

\bigskip

\noindent Five words per line

\noindent\printtable{5}{words}

\bigskip

\noindent Eight words per line

\noindent\printtable{8}{words}

\end{document}
```

The `\storefile` stores the contents of the file under a symbolic name (in this case `words`). Then `\printtable` can print the table using the data.

[image]

We first define an `expl3` equivalent to `\CatchFileDef` for being able to generate variants for it. Then the `\storefile` command is defined: it takes a symbolic name for the word list and the file name as arguments. It stores the entire file in a token list variable (underscores will be absorbed as printable characters).

The `\printtable` gets the desired number of columns and the symbolic name of the list as arguments. It's, as usual, simply translated into a function call.

The function splits the token list corresponding to the symbolic name at commas and does a mapping on the sequence thus obtained. At each step we increment a counter and add the word to a temporary token list; if the counter's value is not the number of columns we add also a `&`, otherwise we add `\\` and reset the counter to zero.

Finally, the entire list is printed inside a `tabular`. You might want to load `longtable` and change `tabular` into `longtable` if the word list is long.

---

For choosing between "row" and "column" order, you can modify it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for the underscore
\usepackage{catchfile,multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \egreg_catchfiledef:nnn \CatchFileDef
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \egreg_catchfiledef:nnn { c }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnv }

\NewDocumentCommand{\storefile}{ m m } % #1 = symbolic name, #2 = file name
 {
  \egreg_catchfiledef:cnn { l_egreg_ #1 _list_tl } { #2 } { \char_set_catcode_other:N \_ }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printtable}{ s m m } % #2 = number of columns, #3 = symbolic name
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   { \egreg_printtablev:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
   { \egreg_printtable:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_egreg_temp_table_tl
\seq_new:N \l_egreg_temp_list_seq
\int_new:N \l_egreg_col_count_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_printtable:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnv \l_egreg_temp_list_seq { , } { l_egreg_ #2 _list_tl }
  \tl_clear:N \l_egreg_temp_table_tl
  \int_zero:N \l_egreg_col_count_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_egreg_temp_list_seq
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_egreg_col_count_int
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_temp_table_tl { ##1 }
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_egreg_col_count_int = #1 }
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_temp_table_tl { \\ } \int_zero:N \l_egreg_col_count_int }
      { \tl_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_temp_table_tl { & } }
   }
  \begin{tabular}{*{#1}{c}}
  \l_egreg_temp_table_tl
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_printtablev:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnv \l_egreg_temp_list_seq { , } { l_egreg_ #2 _list_tl }
  \begin{multicols}{3}\centering
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_egreg_temp_list_seq { ##1 \par }
  \end{multicols}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\storefile{words}{my_words.txt}

\noindent Three words per line

\noindent\printtable{3}{words}

\bigskip

\noindent Five words per line

\noindent\printtable{5}{words}

\bigskip

\noindent Three equispaced columns (column order)

\noindent\printtable*{14}{words}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks @egreg! Is it OK if the words have spaces or underscores in them?

Comment: @user27915816 Underscores can be a problem, but solvable. Spaces shouldn't be, but initial and final ones will be trimmed. I'll add a couple of examples and change the macro to cope with underscores.

Comment: Thanks! If I want to change the ordering to column-order (as opposed to row-order), what would I have to do? (happy to look into this myself if it's too much to ask)

Comment: @user27915816 For column order the best way is to use the `multicol` package (or `\valign`). I'll think about it to get a good interface.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\wordtable{{%
\everyeof{,\relax,}%
\dimen@\z@
\def\word@{\setbox\z@\hbox}%
\def\word@@{}%
\expandafter\@wordtable\@@input words.txt 
\def\word@{\hbox to \dimen@}%
\def\word@@{ \hfill}%
\noindent\expandafter\@wordtable\@@input words.txt
}}

\def\@wordtable#1,{%
 \ifx\relax#1\else
  \word@{\ignorespaces#1\unskip\hfill}\word@@
  \ifdim\dimen@<\wd\z@\dimen@\wd\z@\fi
  \expandafter\@wordtable\fi}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\wordtable

\end{document}
```

From a word file

```
red, yellow, blue, Automatically, formatting, a, table, from, a, file, with, a, list, of, words
```